# Error when gmail create label from an array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, gmail-api

I'm trying to create gmail labels from a list in a connected spreadsheet. I have connected to the spreadsheet and had no issues pulling in the the array. However in the for loop, I'm getting an error of `Invalid Argument` for this line of code:

`var Label = GmailApp.createLabel(selection[i]);`.

I am creating this script in google app script and have already enabled the api for gmail and google sheets. The createLabel function works fine with the array if I input an actual number but it won't seem to read my variable from the for loop. Can you help me figure out the issue?

Below is the rest of my code:

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var selection = sheet.getRange("A1:A13").getValues();

  var arrayLength = selection.length;



  Logger.log(arrayLength);


  //For each value in the array, create a gmail label for it



        for (var i=0; i <arrayLength; i++) { 


            var Label = GmailApp.createLabel(selection[i]);

            Logger.log(Label + "has been created");


        }

      }
```

Comment: Selection is a 2D array, try selection[i][0]

Comment: I updated the line of code to show the below but its still giving me an error.

var Label = GmailApp.createLabel(selection[i][0]);

Comment: I copied your code as is and didn't get any error. Have you checked the value of section?

Comment: Did you mean the value of selection? yes, I checked that. But if you meant the value of section as you wrote it, I'm not sure what you mean by that. I kept getting the invalid argument error on this code. Since this matter was time sensitive I ended up taking out the 2d array completely and went with a work around, but I still want to know if there was a way for me to get this working. One of the weird things that I notices with my original code, it worked initially when I tested it but when I came back to the code the next day it started showing an error. No one else edited it.